# Is there a way to get the steps that visual studio uses in an azure function app deployment?

Tags: .net, azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I've been having issues deploying a .NET 4.7.2 Azure Function App using devops CI/CD pipelines. Since it delayed operations, I just cheated and deployed from Visual Studio by right-clicking on the .proj file and deployed from the "publish" option.

Is there a way for me to get the steps that visual studio used to deploy?

Comment: Visual Studio uses MsDeploy with FTP to deploy artifacts on Azure. It creates a publish settings file in the solution root folder, you may have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to get the steps that visual studio used to deploy?

You can refer to this [article](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/#exercise-4-configuring-continuous-deployment-with-azure-release-pipelines) to deploy from visual studio.

1.Select Clone and select Clone in Visual Studio.

[image]

2.Create Azure Function in Azure Portal and in Visual Studio

3.Setup Continuous Integration with Azure Build Pipelines

4.Configuring Continuous Deployment with Azure Release Pipelines
[image]

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. I know how to create pipelines, and how to deploy. What I'm looking for is the exact steps and configuration that visual studio uses so that I can re-create those steps in my devops pipeline for this specific project.